# Is there EC2 Django Stack with Automatic git or hg deployment

Tags: django, version-control, deployment, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm redoing a badly built web application that my company uses in python/django (after deciding it was the best tool for the job).

I don't have much time to spend on development, which means I have even less time to get it deployed, and since its resource intensive and will be used by a lot of people concurrently, I'd like to be able to take advantage of all the tools that AWS offers, such as RDS, ElastiCache, CloudWatch, and especially any auto scaling tools.

I've seen Heroku and liked it, but I would prefer to use AWS, and the price seems quite high.

I don't mind getting my hands dirty as long as it doesn't take half the development time setting up deployment.

**I'm looking for something we can use, whether it be a service or AMI so that we can deploy automatically from our repository, without spending days configuring it and figuring out how to get it working, and without drastically increasing the price to host our app.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want something quick and simple, maybe consider RightScale's ServerTemplates to get you up and running quickly.  [RightScale](http://www.rightscale.com) have a [free developer account](https://www.rightscale.com/s/create-account.php?sd=Free).  There are a few [Django ServerTemplates](http://www.rightscale.com/library/server_templates/All?s%5Badvanced%5D=&s%5Bfilter_value%5D=django&x=0&y=0&s%5Bfilter_type%5D=title&s%5Bprice%5D=&s%5Bcategory%5D=All&s%5Border%5D=date_desc) and they are all priced for "All Users", so they'll work with the free developer account.

That will get you a base application stack quickly.

Next, I'd look into using fabric (similar to capistrano) and/or github post-commit hooks to automate deployment of your application.

Once you're happy with that and have more time on your hands you could look at adding all the other stuff you want to use (ElastiCache, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll take a look at those. Any comments on BitNami?

Comment: I've used the Bitnami stacks for Redmine, Drupal, and WordPress.  Those worked very well.

Comment: AWS now have cloudformation templates which are similar to rightscales. I created a django one easily within an hour. Here are some samples http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/

Answer (score 0):

Heroku runs on AWS: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/external-services

So, you can use AWS services from Heroku as any EC2 instance. If really wanting it, set Heroku for hard-to-setup services and some little AWS EC2 instance for I-do-myself services.

Answer (score 0):

To automate the deployment you can use a 3rd party tool like capistrano or http://nudow.com.  Capistrano will do a lot of the deployment but you have to host it yourself and you have to do the deployment in a specific way for it to work correctly (such as using the same keys everywhere, etc). Nudow.com is easier to setup and is hosted. It will deploy to your existing infrastructure and will do stuff like versioning. Also it has a lot of tools to do things like minimizing javascript/css and uploading to cloudfront.